# Windows sometimes doesn't boot after Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot installation

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot, grub

After installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on my computer (Ubuntu on a hard drive, the grub and windows 10 on a NVMe drive), sometimes Windows will not boot all the way, and boots slowly when it does boot. After installing Ubuntu my windows boot screen changed to the windows blue logo and the spinning dots (which are kind of morphed now) The dots will randomly freeze, the screen will go black, and then the logo and the dots come back, and then they go away again to a black screen. Sometimes the black screen will load into my windows sign-in page, but sometimes I just get a lit black screen that I can't interact with at all. It also sounds like my fans go at full speed and my hard drive is spinning super fast when that happens. I usually have to do a hard reset if that happens.

I've tried enabling/disabling secure boot. I've already turned fast boot off. I've already tried running the standard ubuntu Grub boot-repair tool.

Comment: What is the filesystem type of your Windows drive? Was Windows 10 installed directly onto it, or was it migrated from any partitioning utility (Ubuntu setup)? Your machine sounds pretty catastrophic if the fans are going full blast. Are you in any way opposed to reformatting your Windows 10 drive, and reinstalling the OS onto it? That's the first thing I would suggest.

Comment: Used to face the same issue a lot. However I can't remember how I dealt with it right now.

Comment: Windows 10 is NTFS, and Ubuntu is GPT. Yeah I did migrate Win10 from the hard drive that Ubuntu is now on onto the NVMe, using MiniTool (which has never given me problem before). I can't remember if I cloned the partition or if I used the migrate OS option. Also, an update, I found that if I press space, enter my PIN to log in, use ctrl-alt-delete and press down arrow twice to select Switch User, my login screen pops up. I've very suspicious of a driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours of trying to properly chain bootloaders, hitting my head against the wall that is GRUB and plenty of failed windows boots I figured out a solution!

For my ASUS laptop GL502VMK I found after searching online that the problem might have something to do with how my BIOS is booting the OS once the chainloading starts, and whether it was booting legacy vs UEFI. So, on a hunch I enabled **CSM Mode** (Compatibility Support Module) in my BIOS and so far I've had several successful, fast (5 seconds compared to previous 25) boots that don't boot to a black screen.

It still has the blue windows logo, and I'm unsure as to why, but this method worked for me!